# Append and remove div with select input in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add and remove a div depending on the value of a select menu. This code works well a first: when the value of the select is 2 div appears. When I return to the first value (1), the div disappears. However if I select the value 2 again, the div is not add again. Any idea ?

```html
 <select id="interv_base_youorthird" name="interv_base[youorthird]" class="form-control">
      <option value="1">Pour moi</option>
      <option value="2">Pour un tiers</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" id="extra-counter" value="0">
```

```js
$("#interv_base_youorthird").change(function(){
    if( $(this).val() == "2" ){
        const index = +$('#extra-counter').val();

        const tmpl = 'hello world';
        //Add sub form
        $('#interv_base_intervExtras').append(tmpl);

        $('#extra-counter').val(index + 1);
    }
    else{
        $('#interv_base_intervExtras').remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you please add full code which you tried. some of your variables/elements are undesigned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is because you `remove()` the `#interv_base_intervExtras` element when you select the first option again. When you move back to the second option `#interv_base_intervExtras` no longer exists in order to read the `data-prototype` attribute from it.

To fix this use `empty()`, instead of `remove()`, to clear the content of the element instead of removing the *entire* element:

```
var $interv = $('#interv_base_intervExtras');

$("#interv_base_youorthird").change(function(){
  if ($(this).val() === "2") {
    const index = parseInt($('#extra-counter').val(), 10);
    const tmpl = $interv.data('prototype').replace(/__name__/g, index);
    $('#interv_base_intervExtras').append(tmpl);
    $('#extra-counter').val(index + 1);
  } else {
    $('#interv_base_intervExtras').empty(); // <-- amend this
  }
});
```

Note that I amended the logic slightly in the above example to cache the `#interv_base_intervExtras` element and to explicitly use `parseInt()` instead of coercing the string to an int using the `+` operator.